# live555 stream from behind router/NAT to public server

Tags: linux, streaming, video-streaming, live555

We have a live555MediaServer on an embedded Linux machine.

The Linux machine is connected to the local LAN, which is behind router/NAT/firewall.

We are able to stream from the media server on the LAN, but would like to be able to access the stream from outside, eg. the Internet.

We have a public server (eg. a server with a public/static IP).

Is it possible to stream to server, so a user can login to the server and watch the stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Aply a NAT rule to the router to masquerade and redirect port 554 or 8554 ( better if your provider blocks the 554 ), or the TCP port you configured to live555.

### Solution 2 (And pretty ugly)

You can open a SSH tunnel from a third host. Sometimes you can't control the Router/NAT/Firewall, so this kind of 'workaround' can do the job...

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Live555 proxy server](http://live555.com/proxyServer/). This is exactly what it's for.